# Rabbitmq is showing a publish rate lower than deliver/ack rate, without a backlog to consume. Can these statistics be accurate?

Tags: rabbitmq

We have been using rabbit for a while, and after a recent deploy to create a new fanout exchange, we got quite spooked by something very curious: in the real time graphs in the management console, and in the REST API, we have queues consistently publishing fewer posts than they are delivering/acking, even though the queue size is hovering around 0!

Sample stats from REST API:

```
    "message_stats": {
    "ack": 149063323,
    "ack_details": {
        "rate": 305.0
    },
    "deliver": 149089898,
    "deliver_details": {
        "rate": 318.8
    },
    "deliver_get": 149089898,
    "deliver_get_details": {
        "rate": 318.8
    },
    "disk_reads": 4058297,
    "disk_reads_details": {
        "rate": 0.0
    },
    "disk_writes": 149084451,
    "disk_writes_details": {
        "rate": 227.6
    },
    "publish": 142374350,
    "publish_details": {
        "rate": 129.6
    },
    "redeliver": 5379,
    "redeliver_details": {
        "rate": 0.0
    }
},
```

The queue has been flatlined at 0 for the time periods we're worrying about.

Here's what the web management console shows:

[image: impossible stats from rabbitmq]

From what we can tell, we are not getting messages multiple times, so we are currently holding the opinion that this is a bug in the statistics collection or reporting. We have not yet had a window to reboot this node as it is a live system. We have discovered no ill-effects yet.

Gory details: Our queue has 240 consumers over 12 connections, and its being published to via a fanout exchange bound to two queues. Both of those queues are exhibiting this behavior. The publish rates of the queues are matching the publish rates of the exchange. The two queues both have a dead letter exchange/queue combo, and require ack. The fanout exchange, and one of the queues are new, and there have been some changes to how these messages are published (used to be published to the default exchange routed to the old queue, now we publish to the new fanout exchange to hit both the old and new queues). The consumers' code has not changed much at all for the old queue (one fewer insert into a postgres table), and the new queue runs code that is extremely similar to the old queue (except only inserting into that one postgres table).

Are these stats possible to encounter in the wild outside of buggy conditions? Could this be caused by a bad topography? What would such a state entail, what side effects would it have, and what types of setups would create this?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution / issue here? We've found this issue today and have no idea what's happening